# How to convert big-number to varchar in Teradata

Tags: casting, teradata

I have a float-type-field which contains big number (more than 20 digits). Then I want to convert it to varchar, without rounding. I tried several queries, but nothing.

Here is for example :

```
SELECT CAST(A AS VARCHAR(25)) AS B
    , TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM CAST(CAST(A AS DECIMAL(25)) AS VARCHAR(25))) AS C
    , TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM CAST(CAST(A AS FORMAT '9(25)') AS VARCHAR(25))) AS D
FROM ( SELECT CAST(79999999999999999999.000 AS FLOAT) A ) t0
```

And the result

```
B : 8.00000000000000E 019
C : 80000000000000000000
D : 80000000000000000000
```

I expect to get '79999999999999999999'

Any advises are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `SELECT CAST(79999999999999999999.000 AS FLOAT)` you get `80.000.000.000.000.000.000,000` as result. The precision of a FLOAT is 15 to 16 digits, your input has 20 significant digits, so it's already rounded during the typecast.

As you can't store numbers like this in a Teradata FLOAT the question is: Where's this *"float-type-field"* coming from? Oracle?

Is there a know maximum **n** for fractional digits?  Then CASTing as DECIMAL(38,**n**) might be ok.

What's your TD release? 14 introduced the NUMBER datatype to easy porting from Oracle.

NUMBER might be used as a *"float-type-field"* with approx. 38 digits.

Comment: t0 table is Teradata and A is stored with float type. I just checked the data again, and I did mistake when ask question. Value of A on t0 is 80000000000000000000.000 instead of 79999999999999999999.000. Other values are 1686287825877540.00000000; 8223372036854780000.00000000. In source file, 16th digit is not zero. And the problem is data type, as you told. Thank you @dnoeth